# Any reason Sitecore 9.x data folder now defaults its location to inside web root?

Tags: installation, sitecore-install-framework

All previous installs to `version 9` had a folder structure like this:

```
/Data
/Databases
/Website
```

Now in `version 9.x` the `/Data directory` is nested inside the `/Website root`. SIF default logic even has code that places it there.

```
"Site.DataFolder": "[joinpath(variable('Site.PhysicalPath'), 'App_Data')]"
```

Just curious if this was intentional?
No performance worries about indexes due to Solr files in a separate directory?
To support Azure deployments?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Is this intentional?

This is intentional because Azure App Services require the Data folder (aptly named App_Data) to be located inside of the website root folder since App Services do not have file system access outside of the website root folder.

Instead of having two different configurations (one for on-prem and one for Azure PaaS) defaulting to the way that works for Azure PaaS allows both topologies to still work with a single configuration.

### No performance worries about indexes due to Solr files in a separate directory?

I am thinking you are thinking of Lucene, as SOLR is handled in a client-server capacity. So, no, this shouldn't have any impact on SOLR.

So then what about Lucene? Well, Lucene isn't supported in Azure, let alone I believe Lucene support in Sitecore 9 has been removed.

But for the sake argument, no. any impact that Lucene would have inside of the directory would be the same impact as outside of the directory. You might be able to argue a performance optimization if Lucene index files were kept on a separate drive but that might be splitting hairs.

### To support Azure deployments?

See answer to the first question.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Assumed it was Azure but was just curious. 

There are still Lucene index files in the /data/indexes out-of-the-box but not used as you mentioned they are in the Solr core folders nested in the Solr install directory. 

I thought years ago they mentioned performance issues with all the read-write stuff happening within an IIS site, but maybe I'm crazy.

Comment: Not crazy, but SOLR isnt reading from those files. SOLR is a completely different server

Comment: Just as a note, Lucene in Sitecore 9 is still supported for non-production standalone environment without xConnect support. But basically, yeah, don't use Lucene:
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/using_solr_or_lucene